Two projective varieties isomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ but not over $\mathbb{R}$.
Some context: Given $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{K})$ closed, we say that $X$ is defined over a subfield $F$ of $\mathbb{K}$ if $I(X)$, the homogeneous ideal of $X$, can be generated by homogeneous polynomials with coefficients in $F$, i.e.
\begin{align}I(X)=(F_1,\ldots,F_r),\,F_i\in F[Z_0,\ldots,Z_n]_{d_i}.\end{align}
Denote $X(F)$ the set of points in $X$ that can be represented by $(n+1)$-tuple $(Z_0\ldots,Z_n)\in F^{n+1}\setminus\{(0,\ldots,0)\}$. Given $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{K}), Y\subset\mathbb{P}^m(\mathbb{K})$ closed defined over $F$, a  regular map $\psi: X\to Y$ is defined over $F$ if locally it's of the form:
\begin{align}
[Z]\to[P_0(Z),\ldots,P_m(Z)]\,\,\,\text{with}\,\,\,P_i\in F[Z_0,\ldots,Z_n]_d
\end{align}
(of course $(P_0(Z),\ldots,P_m(Z))\neq (0,\ldots,0)$ in the relative open.
With the above notations we have a natural map $\psi: X(F)\to Y(F)$.
Now in my situation we have $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$ and $F=\mathbb{R}$ and\begin{align}
X=V(Z_0^2-Z_1^2-Z_2^2-Z_3^2), Y=V(Z_0^2+Z_1^2-Z_2^2-Z_3^2)\subset\mathbb{P}^3(\mathbb{C}).
\end{align}
Of course $X$ and $Y$ are defined over $\mathbb{R}$, I want to prove that they are isomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$ but not over $\mathbb{R}$.
The first part is easy because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed so the quadratics forms relative to $X$ and $Y$ are projectively equivalent and therefore isomorphic. For the second part I noted that every regular map between $X$ and $Y$ defined over $\mathbb{R}$ gives a continuous map (for the euclidean topology) $\psi: X(\mathbb{R})\to Y(\mathbb{R})$. So I want to argue by contradiction using the latter part, but I'm stuck.
Any help? Thanks

For quadratic forms, the rank is the sole invariant over the complex numbers while the rank and signature are two invariants over the real numbers. Anyway, $ X $ and $ Y $ are not isomorphic over $ \mathbb{R} $ as $ X(\mathbb{R}) $ is diffeomorphic to $ S^2 $ while $ Y(\mathbb{R}) $ is diffeomorphic to $ S^1 \times S^1 $.

Sorry, but $Y(\mathbb{R})$ shouldn't be diffeomorphic to $S^1\times\mathbb{R}$?

No. It is a submanifold of P^3(R) and therefore, has to be compact.

Right thanks!..

You can also see the diffeomorphism pretty directly, right? The vanishing set consists of (projective) points $[z_{0} : z_{1} : z_{2} : z_{3}]$ satisfying $z_{0}^{2}+z_{1}^{2} = z_{2}^{2}+z_{3}^{2}$, which just looks like two "independent" circles up to rescaling. But maybe this argument isn't sufficiently rigorous in some way. :)
